# codeigniter inner join tables syntax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

error msg: Unknown column 'category' in 'where clause'

i have to inner join two tables. what should be the correct query?
Or what parameter should i put in $query->get()? If I only put 'film', it cannot find 'category' column in another table.

```
    $query = $this->db->select('title, name as category, rental_rate, length')->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

    $query = $this->db->join('film_category', 'film_category.film_id = film.film_id');

    $query = $this->db->join('category', 'film_category.category_id = category.category_id');

    if(strlen($query_array['title'])) {
        $query->like('title', $query_array['title']);
    }

    if(strlen($query_array['category'])) {
        $query->where('category', $query_array['category']);
    }

    $data['films'] = $query->get('film', 20, $this->uri->segment(6));
```

Comment: Do you have `category` column within your table I think it should be `name` instead of `category`

Comment: can you provide table schema

Comment: yes, column name is "name" instead of "category", however, even if i change it to $query->where('name', $query_array['category']);
same thing: error msg: Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `film` WHERE `title` LIKE '%ac%' ESCAPE '!' AND `name` = 'Horror' AND `length` > '100'

Comment: film_category table has 2 columns: film_id, category_id;;;
category table has 2 columns: category_id, name

Comment: you can use $this->db->query("your sql here");  if you want to get done with it..

Comment: Instead of `$query->where('category', $query_array['category']);` shouldn't it be `$this->db->where('category', $query_array['category']);` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->select('title, name as category, rental_rate, length')->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
$this->db->from('film'); /*I assume that film was the table name*/
$this->db->join('film_category', 'film_category.film_id = film.film_id');
$this->db->join('category', 'category.category_id = film_category.category_id');

$query = $this->db->get();

var_dump($query);
```

Double check that code I added and make sure that on category table, the column is called category_id, and not just id, and that under film_category, there's a category_id column.
If with the code I submitted, you still get the error, try to replace the first line with

```
$this->db->select('title, name, rental_rate, length')->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
```

I'm not sure if using a name that matches a table will cause a trouble with CodeIgniter and ActiveRecord.

Hope that helps.